# Symfony2 how to get data from a specific field of an entity to make a form?

Tags: forms, symfony

I have an entity object with a size field (which is an array) with different size available. (ex : s, m, xl). But not all the objects have the same size available. I fill this field in a form like this =>

```
->add('size', 'choice', array('choices' => array('xs' => 'XS', 's' => 'S', 'm' => 'M', 'l' => 'L', 'xl' => 'XL'), 'multiple' => true, 'expanded' => true))
```

so now I would like an other form where the user can choose a available size (for the object).
the type entity is not working in my case because I don't look for an full entity.

I try this:

```
$builder->add('size', 'choice', array(
'class' => 'MyWebshopBundle:Size',
'property' => 'name',
'expanded' => false,
));
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

OK I would make this metta data driven by creating some sort of stock count against sizes relationship to the relating entity.

Then perform a query builder in your form something like

```
    $builder->add('sizes', 'entity', array(
                 'class' => 'MYBUNDLE:Sizes',
                 'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($thisEntity) {
                                   return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                                       ->innerJoin('s.clothing', 'c')
                                       ->where('c = :entity')
                                       ->andWhere('s.stock > :stock')
                                       ->setParameters(['entity' => $thisEntity, 'stock' => 0])
                                       ->orderBy('s.size', 'ASC');
                 },
      ));
```

Now obviously there is a missing join but you should get the gist

Comment: wow we can do that. That framework impress me everyday. Thx for your answer i am going to try that